# haskell `stack` commands for uninstall/clean up?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

`stack setup` download and installs GHC for project,

> `~/.stack/programs`,
>   `~/.stack/snapshots`
>   and somewhere else which I don't know yet)
>
> `stack build` downloads dependencies and build them.
>   `~/.stack/setup-exe-cache` and somewhere else.

I want to clean up project-wide ghc and downloaded dependencies/build output from them, plus all the other project related things on my disk.

There's no way to do this other than just manually delete them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`stack clean` command clears local cache in `.stack-work`.

The feature for cleaning `.stack` cache is not implemented yet. See this GitHub issue:

- https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/133

`stack setup` installs GHC for project but it stores GHC globally (so you don't need to install GHC again for another project if this project uses same version of GHC).

You can just do `rm -rf .stack-work` to clean project local build cache (built modules, github dependencies for project, etc.). Though, `rm -rf .stack-work` won't work for multipackage project. Just do `stack clean --full` to clear local cache completely for project.

To clean global cache, you can just do `rm -rf ~/.stack`.

Thus, again, citing latest comment from issue discussion:

> The garbage collection question definitely needs to be answered in some form or another. If possible, I think I might find a documentation solution preferable to a new command. It would be great if the manual discussed the directory structure of `~/.stack` and explained what directories were safe to delete.